# MongoDb Compound Indexes: Performance Based on Order of Keys

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The [MongoDb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) provides an example of inventory items to explain why the order of the keys is significant to performance.

It provides a sample data set:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "f1", type: "food", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "f2", type: "food", quantity: 100 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "p1", type: "paper", quantity: 200 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "p2", type: "paper", quantity: 150 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "f3", type: "food", quantity: 300 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "t1", type: "toys", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "a1", type: "apparel", quantity: 250 }
{ "_id" : 8, "item" : "a2", type: "apparel", quantity: 400 }
{ "_id" : 9, "item" : "t2", type: "toys", quantity: 50 }
{ "_id" : 10, "item" : "f4", type: "food", quantity: 75 }
```

It compares the performance of 2 similar compound indexes.  Notice the order of the keys is reversed to make the point:

```
db.inventory.createIndex( { quantity: 1, type: 1 } )
db.inventory.createIndex( { type: 1, quantity: 1 } )
```

It performs the query using the 1st index:

```
db.inventory.find(
   { quantity: { $gte: 100, $lte: 300 }, type: "food" }
).hint({ quantity: 1, type: 1 }).explain("executionStats")
```

For the 1st index, the documentation states:

```
"totalKeysExamined" : 5,
"totalDocsExamined" : 2,
```

Then, the query for the 2nd index:

```
db.inventory.find(
   { quantity: { $gte: 100, $lte: 300 }, type: "food" }
).hint({ type: 1, quantity: 1 }).explain("executionStats")
```

It shows the result:

```
 "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
 "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
```

Finally, it concludes:

> For this example query, the compound index { type: 1, quantity: 1 } is more efficient than the compound index { quantity: 1, type: 1 }.

I can see how order can affect performance if the data had **many** food items and **few** items satisfying the quantity range, or **vice versa**.  However, I think this is different from the point that is being made in the documentation.

There are 5 items which satisfy the quantity requirement.  There are 4 which satisfy the type requirement.  I do not understand how the 2nd index results in totalKeysExamined of 2 vs. 5 in the 1st index.  I see 4 food items.  So, my gut is telling me it's 4 vs. 5.

Hopefully, some additional explanation can clear up my confusion.  I want to fully understand the significance of compound index key order.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I see it, now.  It helps to visualize the 2 lists under the different scenarios.

Here is the list by type, then quantity:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "a1", type: "apparel", quantity: 250 }   
{ "_id" : 8, "item" : "a2", type: "apparel", quantity: 400 } 
{ "_id" : 10, "item" : "f4", type: "food", quantity: 75 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "f2", type: "food", quantity: 100 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "f3", type: "food", quantity: 300 }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "f1", type: "food", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "p1", type: "paper", quantity: 200 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "p2", type: "paper", quantity: 150 }
{ "_id" : 9, "item" : "t2", type: "toys", quantity: 50 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "t1", type: "toys", quantity: 500 }
```

Here is the list by quantity, then type:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "f1", type: "food", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "t1", type: "toys", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 8, "item" : "a2", type: "apparel", quantity: 400 } 
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "f3", type: "food", quantity: 300 }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "a1", type: "apparel", quantity: 250 }   
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "p1", type: "paper", quantity: 200 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "p2", type: "paper", quantity: 150 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "f2", type: "food", quantity: 100 }
{ "_id" : 10, "item" : "f4", type: "food", quantity: 75 }
{ "_id" : 9, "item" : "t2", type: "toys", quantity: 50 }
```

Going on Veeram's comments, it seems like with the former index, we need only hit the index once to find a food with the requested quantity.  Once we land, we just iterate in order.  However, if we have to look first for quantity, we will have a number of different types mixed within, and so we have to skip over the other types to get only the foods.

Comment: Which mongo version?

Comment: npm list mongodb shows 2.2.33.  My question concerns understanding the documentation, though.

Comment: If I understand this right docs are not correct  for index 1 the count for keys should be 6. So the keys should be 6 and 2 for index1 and index 2 respectively.

Comment: I think they are correct for index 1.  There are 5 items with quantities gte 100 and lte 300.

Comment: My question is why 2 vs. 5 (or 6)?  How can that be?

Comment: I don't think so. You missed the direction aka order when you search the index. So index 1 will be ordered by quantity and type so you have to scan 6 keys and for index 2 ordered by type and quantity so only 2 keys. I was able to confirm this behavior on both 3.2 and 3.6 version

Comment: Seems to violate the commutative property of mathematics.  If I am looking at the list sorted by type, I will encounter 4 food items.  For each of those, I need to evaluate quantity to see if condition is satisfied.  How can I only look at 2?

Comment: I think you evaluate at the same time. Not after getting type first and then quantity. So it will be 2. Not sure how it works behind the scene. So somehow index knows you don't have to consider docs with quantity greater outside the bound.

Comment: Are you saying that if we reverse the order of the query to type and then quantity, the result would be different, and index 1 would be more efficient?

Comment: No i don't think the fields order in the query matters at all. It's all how index fields data is stored and it's order. It's hard to reason when you don't know how it all works in reality. So may be there are few other things at play here. I'm also not sure why it is 6 for index 1 when I run the explain. Hopefully someone can explain it for us.

Comment: Thanks for going over this with me.  I think you made me understand.  I edited my question at the bottom to lay it out.

Comment: Np. Here is a good [article](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) that I just found. Hopefully it will help you understand things little better.